# Mounting an external disk changes permissions on mount point directory

Tags: permissions, mount, chown

On Debian 11, mounting an external disk changes permissions on the mount point directory. The disk is formatted as `ext4`.

Is this normal behavior?

Create directory:

```
user@debian:/media$ mkdir external2
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘external2’: Permission denied
user@debian:/media$ sudo mkdir external2
```

Check ownership:

```
user@debian:/media$ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Aug 17 20:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4096 Jul  9 21:11 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  4  2021 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 12  2021 external
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 17 20:19 external2
```

Change ownership to `user`:

```
user@debian:/media$ chown -R user:user /media/external2
chown: changing ownership of '/media/external2': Operation not permitted
user@debian:/media$ sudo chown -R user:user /media/external2
```

And check ownership:

```
user@debian:/media$ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Aug 17 20:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4096 Jul  9 21:11 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  4  2021 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 12  2021 external
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 Aug 17 20:19 external2
```

Mount hard disk:

```
user@debian:/media$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/external2
```

Check ownership:

```
user@debian:/media$ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Aug 17 20:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4096 Jul  9 21:11 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  4  2021 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 12  2021 external
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 12  2021 external2
```

EDIT: for the sake of transparency, I'm leaving this question, but I have another one which may be related:
[Strange rsync behavior deleting already transferred files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/714266/strange-rsync-behavior-deleting-already-transferred-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is normal and expected behavior on all mount points on all Unix-like systems.

When you are mounting the external hard disk, the root directory of the external HD's filesystem is placed on top of the mount point directory, and the mount point directory is "hidden under" the new filesystem.

The root directory of external HD's filesystem has its own ownership and permissions, and once you have mounted the external disk, those are the permissions you'll see - because you no longer see the directory you used as the mount point, but the root directory of the filesystem you mounted onto it.

When you unmount the other filesystem, you will again see the original permissions of the mount point directory, as the root directory of the filesystem that was covering up the mount-point directory is unmounted.

You may have expected the ownership to reflect the identity of the user that mounted the filesystem, but that is the exception, not the rule: it can only happen when mounting a filesystem with no support for Unix-style ownerships and permissions (like the filesystem types of the FAT family), and the mount point has been pre-arranged to allow regular users to use the `mount` command without `sudo`.

Mounting a filesystem has significant security implications, and so normally only root (or someone with unlimited `sudo` access) will be able to use the full unrestricted forms of the `mount` command. But it is possible to allow non-root users to use `mount` without `sudo` *at pre-arranged mount points only*. To do that, the system administrator must first write an `/etc/fstab` entry that includes one of the mount options `user`, `users` or `owner`. The differences are:

- `users`: any user can mount, and any user can unmount
- `user`: any user can mount, but only root or the user who mounted the filesystem will be able to unmount it
- `owner`: like `user`, but with the added requirement that the user must own the device node they're trying to mount (This would allow the mounting of hot-plugged removable drives for locally logged-in users only, in systems that are configured to grant the ownership of hot-plugged devices to the user that is logged in locally. Many distributions, including Debian, prefer to not do it this way, but use a separate removable-media mount helper like `udisks2` instead. See `man udisks`.)

To use such a pre-arranged mount point, the non-root user must use the `mount` command in its short form, i.e. specifying only the device to mount or the mount point directory, *not both*. `mount` will then look up the rest of the details from `/etc/fstab`, enforcing the mount options and other parameters specified by the system administrator.

If you ever need to access files or sub-directories that have been hidden by another filesystem being mounted on top of them, it is possible by making a *bind mount* of the parent filesystem (using `mount --bind`, *not* `mount --rbind`) and accessing the mount-point directory through the bind mount.

Example using your setup. Start with the external disk unmounted:

```
sudo touch /media/external2/This_will_be_hidden_by_external_disk
ls /media/external2       # now you see it
sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/external2
ls /media/external2       # now you don't!
sudo mount --bind / /mnt
ls /mnt/media/external2   # here you will see it again!
sudo umount /mnt          # to clean up the bind mount
```

If a mount point directory is not empty, `systemd`-based systems will issue a warning when mounting filesystems according to `/etc/fstab` at boot time.

Comment: Do the underlying mount point permissions matter to the system when accesing files in that "external HD"?

Comment: The mount point permissions might prevent you from mounting if you don't have root privileges; but once the filesystem has been successfully mounted, the permissions of the underlying mount point have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had this same problem on AIX, where the underlying mount point permissions actually matter to git and other programs, we could see this with `stat /mount/..` as non-root user which returned `Permission denied` error, although `/mount/..` is just `/` and `stat /` worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are mounting with `sudo`, so it is normal that `root` is the owner on the mounted directory.