# Strange rsync behavior deleting already transferred files

Tags: rsync, ownership

I'm facing a strange issue with rsync.

The server hard disk has failed and I've replaced it with a another one.
The rsync command I'm using is **identical** and there have been no other changes.

There were no rsync errors with the old disk and no error messages.
All files would transfer normally.

With the replacement disk, I'm experiencing some strange behavior.

This the command:
`sudo rsync -PaShzH --mkpath --delete --stats -e 'ssh -p XXXX -i /key' /source/ user@server.org:/destination/`

rsync starts and I can see the files being transferred to the destination.

After several hours rsync fails with:
`rsync: [receiver] mkstemp "/directory/file" failed: No such file or directory (2)`

What's strange is that:
(1) When rsync fails, it somehow seems to delete all the transferred files on the destination.
So, when I check the destination, it's **completely** empty.

(2) On occasion, it also seems to change the ownership of the destination mount point from user to root.

I've tested the disk but unless I'm missing something, it looks OK:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   195   195   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       18299
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   188   175   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       7591
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       8132
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   060   060   000    Old_age   Always       -       29612
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       91
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       80
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   198   198   000    Old_age   Always       -       8902
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   105   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       47
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
```

I have no idea why rsync fails with the very same command which worked with the old disk.

Also, it's unclear why it would delete all the files transferred when it encounters an error.
I would have expected the already transferred files to remain.

EDIT: I'm also seeing these errors:
`recv_generator: mkdir "/directory/file" failed: Permission denied (13)`

Comment: When `rsync` fails, is the disk in fact unmounted? This would explain why it fails and why the files seems to have disappeared.

Comment: `mkstemp` being unable to create a file is unusual, is the file system running out of inodes, or worse? Also I'd probably replace `--delete` with `--partial`; a `--delete` run could be done afterwards.

Comment: `--delete` deletes extraneous files from the destination dirs... is this what you want to do?

Comment: @Kusalananda. It just failed again. The disk seems to be mounted correctly: `mount -l | grep /dev/sd` shows `/dev/sdb on /directory type ext4 (rw,relatime)`. Also, the ownership of the mount point has changed. It was `user:user` and it's now `root:root`. The disk seems to be empty as I see no files in the mount point and `df -h` shows `/dev/sdb        3.6T   12K  3.4T   1% /directory`.
@thrig @telometto the `--delete` flag is intentional. It never caused any issues in the past and worked as intended. I thought the disk had failed (it's in an external USB enclosure), but I see no SMART errors.

Comment: I'm very embarrassed to admit that a conflicting `rsync` cron job, was deleting the files. I had checked the crontab for `user`, but I had omitted to check the one for `root`. That explains why files were being deleted and why the folder ownership was changing. Thanks for your help and sorry to have wasted your time.